# angular return Promise ou Observable

Tags: angular, async-await

I'm learning Angular, after research, I partially solved my problem (I think). It was called asynchronous.
Returns database number to generate document.
But now I'm not able to get the returned value. I see that the service returns
value (or at least in the log it shows value), but it returns **undefined**.

file **service**

```
 async numberdoc(year: number): Promise<any>  {
    // return the value
    await this.http.get<any>(`${this.url + 'docnumber'}/${year}`).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        let resInt = +res.valueOf();
        console.log('Number return service: ' + resInt);
        return resInt;
      })
    );
  }
```

Console Log

```
setor.service.ts:56 Number return service: 148 <== Number returned from database
```

file **app**

```
async getnumberdoc(year: number): Promise<any> {
    await this.service
      .numberdoc(year)
      .then((retorno: any) => {
        return retorno;
      })
      .catch(
        (err) => console.log(err)
      );
  }


onClick() {
    
    let value = await this.getnumberdoc(this.year);
    console.log(`async result: ${value}`);

}
```

```
app.component.ts:170 async result: **undefined**
```

Comment: async onClick()